# Custom search Dashboard widget

Tags: search, wpdb, dashboard

I have a custom dashboard that searches based on meta value. It works ok except that I now need to restrict the results/search to a specific  post type, `shop-subscription`.

This is the query I have, what I am looking for is help to add the check for post type.

```php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE meta_key LIKE '_child_name'  AND meta_value LIKE '%$s_query%' OR meta_key LIKE '%_child_name_%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$s_query%' LIMIT 0,100;");
```

Comment: You should prepare queries, never insert variables directly into an SQL query it's a big security risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's start off by cleaning up the query you have above. I've put it into [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to make it easier to read.

```php
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM {$tablename} -- you should use interpolation when working in a string that can have variables
WHERE
( -- Your query will only ever match one row of meta_key at a time, so combine these and OR them
    meta_key = '_child_name'  -- changed LIKE to = since you're not doing a wildcard match
OR
    meta_key LIKE '%_child_name_%'
)
AND -- you only need to check against this once
    meta_value LIKE '%{$s_query}%'
LIMIT 0,100;
SQL;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Going through the comments:

- The WordPress coding standards recommend using `{}` brackets when doing [string interpolation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) when using variables inside of `""` double quotes or Heredoc syntax.
- You were querying for `meta_key = '_child_name'` and `meta_key LIKE '%_child_name_%'`. Since SQL can only return one row per match of `meta_key`, I put these into a single condition and `OR`'d them.
- You were doing `meta_key LIKE '_child_name'` - since you weren't matching a wildcard (`%`), the `LIKE` was superfluous.
- You had `meta_value LIKE '%$s_query%'` twice, you only need to do that once since you can only ever get one row matching back at a time (e.g. doing `meta_value = 'A' AND meta_value = 'B'` would always return zero results). Also note the use of interpolation wrapped in `{}` here.

One more note, the coding standards for WordPress would also encourage you to escape your query properly using methods like `esc_like` or `$wpdb->prepare()`, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

#### Restricting By Post Type

Post meta rows relate to the post table via the post ID, so to restrict your results to the `shop-subscription` post type, we can `JOIN` the posts table like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM {$tablename}
JOIN wp_posts p ON (p.post_type = 'shop-subscription' AND p.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE
(
    meta_key = '_child_name' 
OR
    meta_key LIKE '%_child_name_%'
)
AND
    meta_value LIKE '%{$s_query}%'
LIMIT 0,100;
```

This assumes you're pulling rows from the `wp_postmeta` table (as the value of `$tablename`). If you're using a different table, you should properly update teh query to relate the post ID to the meta row ID column.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer and explanation it works perfectly